# Get Data Between Two Table Where There are no relation between Them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table called

```
Supplier Table

Customer Table
```

there are no relation between them 

First Table `Customer` have this data 
[Customer  Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPmjH.jpg)

Second Table  `Supplier` have this data
[Supplier Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeupl.jpg)

I need to see data as this

```
SupplierID   CustomerName
1               Yahia
1               Ahmed
1               Ali
2               Yahia 
2               Ahmed
2               Ali
3               Yahia
3               Ahmed
3               Ali
```

Note That No Relation Between Two table 
can achieve this relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but it seems you want a cartesian product of those two tables. This is easily done with a cross join.

```
select *
from supplier s
cross join Customer c
```

Comment: i forgot cross join 
Thanks Done (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You might want this

```
select 
     SupplierID,CustomerName 
from 
     Supplier
cross join
     Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply each rows of a table with every rows of an other table, you can use `CROSS JOIN`

```
  SELECT S.SupplierID, C.CustomerName
      FROM supplier S
     CROSS JOIN Customer C
```

[MSDN about CROSS JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)